# Extracting strings for translation from VB6 code

Tags: ruby, parsing, localization, vb6, internationalization

I have a legacy VB application that still has some life in it, and I am wanting to translate it to another language.

I plan to write a Ruby script, possibly utilising a parser, to extract all strings from the three million lines of source, replace them with constants, and move them to a string resource file that can be used to provide translations.

Is anyone aware of a script/library that could be used to intelligently extract the strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of any existing off-the-shelf tool that you could use. We created a tool like this at my work and it worked well. The FRM file format is quite simple (although only [briefly documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa241723(v=vs.60).aspx)). We wrote a tool that (1) extracted all strings from control definitions and (2) generated the code to reload them at runtime during `Form_Load`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Mark, did you build in any intelligence as to what what strings were selected?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. We made sure to extract every relevant property from the design-time definitions in the top of the FRM files. There were also strings in the runtime code (e.g. bottom of FRM files and throughout .BAS files). We extracted those manually (tedious) though we did write an add-in for the VB6 IDE to ease this process - we can right-click on a string and have it automatically (1) added to the external translation file and (2) replaced in the code with the code to load the translation.